# get and store values from many selects at same time

Tags: javascript, html

I got 7 `select` that I need to read their value to use it later on, but I can only read the value of the firts select, if I tried to read a second one or more, it crashes.

I need to be able to identify which `selects'` value is different from `""` to read it, but if the value is equal to `""`, then ignore it.

This is my script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#MENU").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
        $("." + optionValue).show();
      } else {
        $(".box").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});

function myFuction() {
  //Getting Value
  //var selValue = document.getElementById("singleSelectDD").value;
  var selObj = document.getElementById("MENU");
  var selValue = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;
  //Setting Value
  document.getElementById("valorsel").value = selValue;
}

function ELEMENTO() {
  //Getting Value
  //var selValue = document.getElementById("singleSelectDD").value;
  var modifica1 = document.getElementById("AREA");
  var modifica2 = document.getElementById("BANCO");
  var modifica3 = document.getElementById("USOCFDI");
  var modifica4 = document.getElementById("DEPARTAMENTO");
  var modifica5 = document.getElementById("EMPRESA");
  var modifica6 = document.getElementById("GIRO");
  var modifica7 = document.getElementById("NEGOCIO");
  var modval1 = modifica1.options[modifica1.selectedIndex].value;
  var modval2 = modifica2.option[modifica2.selectedIndex].value;
  var modval3 = modifica3.option[modifica3.selectedIndex].value;
  var modval4 = modifica4.option[modifica4.selectedIndex].value;
  var modval5 = modifica5.option[modifica5.selectedIndex].value;
  var modval6 = modifica6.option[modifica6.selectedIndex].value;
  var modval7 = modifica7.option[modifica7.selectedIndex].value;
}

document.getElementById("Actualiza").addEventListener("click", function Act() {
  var res = document.getElementById("modfinal").value;
  document.getElementById("IDDATO").innerHTML = res;
  var txt = document.getElementById("valorsel").value;
  document.getElementById("RESULTADO").innerHTML = txt;
  var txt2 = document.getElementById("GLOBAL").value;
  document.getElementById("GLOB").innerHTML = txt2;
});

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function Act() {
  var res = document.getElementById("modfinal").value;
  document.getElementById("IDDATO").innerHTML = res;
  var txt = document.getElementById("valorsel").value;
  document.getElementById("RESULTADO").innerHTML = txt;
  var txt2 = document.getElementById("GLOBAL").value;
  document.getElementById("GLOB").innerHTML = txt2;



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="CXP" action="Guarda_CXP2.php" method="post" target="_blank">
  <h1 style="text-align: center"> Cuentas por Pagar </h1>
  <p>Seleccione una opción</p>
  <div>
    <select name="MENU" id="MENU" onchange="myFuction()">
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="1">Area</option>
      <option value="2">Bancos</option>
      <option value="3">CFDI</option>
      <option value="4">Departamentos</option>
      <option value="5">Empresa</option>
      <option value="6">Giro Comercial</option>
      <option value="7">Negocio</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <p>Texto Global</p>
    <input type="text" name="GLOBAL" id="GLOBAL" value="" placeholder="Texto global">
  </div>
  <div class="1 box">
    <p>Seleccione el Area deseada</p>
    <select name="AREA" id="AREA" class="HIJOS" onclick="ELEMENTO()">
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="1">AREA 1</option>
      <option value="2">AREA 2</option>
      <option value="3">AREA 3 </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="2 box">
    <p>Selecione el Banco deseado</p>
    <select name="BANCO" id="BANCO" class="HIJOS" onchange="ELEMENTO()">
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="1">BANCO 1</option>
      <option value="2">BANCO 2</option>
      <option value="3">BANCO 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="3 box">
    <p> Ingrese el uso de CFDI</p>
    <select name="USOCFDI" id="USOCFDI" class="HIJOS" onchange="ELEMENTO()">
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="1">CFDI 01</option>
      <option value="2">CFDI 02</option>
      <option value="3">CFDI 03</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="4 box">
    <p> Seleccione el Deparmaneto deseado </p>
    <select name="DEPARTAMENTO" id="DEPARTAMENTO" class="HIJOS" onchange="ELEMENTO()">
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="1">DEPARTAMENTO 1</option>
      <option value="2">DEPARTAMENTO 2</option>
      <option value="3">DEPARTAMENTO 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="5 box">
    <p> Seleccione la Empresa deseada</p>
    <select name="EMPRESA" id="EMPRESA" class="HIJOS" onchange="ELEMENTO()">
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="1">EMPRESA 1</option>
      <option value="2">EMPRESA 2</option>
      <option value="3">EMPRESA 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="6 box">
    <p> Seleccione el Giro Comercial</p>
    <select name="GIRO" id="GIRO" class="HIJOS" onchange="ELEMENTO()">
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="1">GIRO 1</option>
      <option value="2">GIRO 2</option>
      <option value="3">GIRO 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="7 box">
    <p> Ingrese el tipo de Negocio</p>
    <select name="NEGOCIO" id="NEGOCIO" class="HIJOS" onchange="ELEMENTO()">
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="1">NEGOCIO 1</option>
      <option value="2">NEGOCIO 2</option>
      <option value="3">NEGOCIO 3</option>
    </select>
  </div><br>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="button" name="button">
    <input type="submit" id="Actualiza" value="Actualizar" name="Actualizar" onclick="Act">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Agregar" name="Agregar">
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="valorsel" id="valorsel" class="form-control" placeholder="ID para tabla">
  <input type="text" name="modfinal" id="modfinal" class="form-control" placeholder="ID para dato">
  <p name="RESULTADO" id="RESULTADO"></p>
  <p name="IDDATO" id="IDDATO"></p>
  <p name="GLOB" id="GLOB"></p>
</form>
```

This is some text box I use to be able to watch if it is working:

```
<input type="text" name="modfinal" id="modfinal" class="form-control" placeholder="ID para dato">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ulises9663/x2z3bjyo/

Comment: Where does come from element with `id="AREA"` ? Also, you say *"...it crashes"*, in which way? There's error in the console, what happens? It would be great if you add a snippet of [mcve] with at least two `select`, then we could test and debug it for you

Comment: the `id=AREA` is my first `select` the one I post is the second `select`, sorry for the confusion I made, english is not my mother languaje...

Comment: The console read the following:0: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference

Comment: here it is https://jsfiddle.net/Ulises9663/x2z3bjyo/

Comment: I'm going to edit your question and add as snippet here, ok?

Comment: Ok, thak you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, there's much code on your example and I don't know exactly what is the desired output and objective, but one thing I can suggest you to do to be much easier is:

- Create a global variable, let's call it `objSelecteds`.
- `ELEMENTO()` function can be shortened, no need to get every element every time it is called, in the HTML, pass `this` as parameter, then inside the function the parameter can be used to access the element directly.
- With that, now use the `<select>` element `id` as key and the value of the selected option as value to insert into our `objSelecteds`.
- That way, each select that got modiefied will have it's `id` and selected value saved inside `objSelecteds`.
- Now, when you need to check the selected values, you only need to access the `objSelecteds` and see each value for each select.

Take a look at the code below, run the snippet and made some changes to the selects, see if you understand it and if it helps you:

```js
let objSelecteds = {}

function ELEMENTO(self) {   
  let modval = self.options[self.selectedIndex].value;
  objSelecteds[self.id] = modval;

  console.clear()
  console.log(objSelecteds)
}

function checkSelections(){
  let validSelections = []
  for (let key in objSelecteds){
    let selectValue = objSelecteds[key]
    if (key != "" && key != null){
      validSelections.push(key)
    }
  }
   console.clear()
  console.log("Those selections are valid and have some value:", validSelections)
  return validSelections
}
```

```html
<button onclick="checkSelections()">Check selections</button>

<div class="1 box">
    <p>Seleccione el Area deseada</p>
    <select name="AREA" id="AREA" class="HIJOS" onclick="ELEMENTO(this)">
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="1">AREA 1</option>
      <option value="2">AREA 2</option>
      <option value="3">AREA 3 </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="2 box">
    <p>Selecione el Banco deseado</p>
    <select name="BANCO" id="BANCO" class="HIJOS" onchange="ELEMENTO(this)">
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="1">BANCO 1</option>
      <option value="2">BANCO 2</option>
      <option value="3">BANCO 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="3 box">
    <p> Ingrese el uso de CFDI</p>
    <select name="USOCFDI" id="USOCFDI" class="HIJOS" onchange="ELEMENTO(this)">
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="1">CFDI 01</option>
      <option value="2">CFDI 02</option>
      <option value="3">CFDI 03</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="4 box">
    <p> Seleccione el Deparmaneto deseado </p>
    <select name="DEPARTAMENTO" id="DEPARTAMENTO" class="HIJOS" onchange="ELEMENTO(this)">
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="1">DEPARTAMENTO 1</option>
      <option value="2">DEPARTAMENTO 2</option>
      <option value="3">DEPARTAMENTO 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="5 box">
    <p> Seleccione la Empresa deseada</p>
    <select name="EMPRESA" id="EMPRESA" class="HIJOS" onchange="ELEMENTO(this)">
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="1">EMPRESA 1</option>
      <option value="2">EMPRESA 2</option>
      <option value="3">EMPRESA 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="6 box">
    <p> Seleccione el Giro Comercial</p>
    <select name="GIRO" id="GIRO" class="HIJOS" onchange="ELEMENTO(this)">
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="1">GIRO 1</option>
      <option value="2">GIRO 2</option>
      <option value="3">GIRO 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="7 box">
    <p> Ingrese el tipo de Negocio</p>
    <select name="NEGOCIO" id="NEGOCIO" class="HIJOS" onchange="ELEMENTO(this)">
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="1">NEGOCIO 1</option>
      <option value="2">NEGOCIO 2</option>
      <option value="3">NEGOCIO 3</option>
    </select>
  </div><br>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if statement to see if it is empty or not. See the example below:

```
function ELEMENTO(){
       var modifica1 = document.getElementById("BANCO");
       var modval1= modifica1.options[modifica1.selectedIndex].value;
       var val = modval1.trim();
       if(val){
            document.getElementById("modfinal").value = modval1;
       }
}
```

Hope this helps!